# not getting proper current address google map sdk iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk

I am using googlemap sdk but not able to find current location properly on device like in goole map.
I am getting proper latitude and longitude when I paste this latitude and longitude in browser I am getting proper full address with House No. but not getting House No. in GMSAddress . Here's my code:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [mapView_ addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:0 context:nil];
  }
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
      CLLocation *location = [object myLocation];
      //...
      NSLog(@"Location, %@,", location);

  ```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D target =
  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);


  lat=location.coordinate.latitude;
  lon=location.coordinate.longitude;

  [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
      NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");
      for(GMSAddress* addressObj in [response results])

      {

          NSDictionary*dict=[response results];
          NSLog(@"coordinate.latitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.latitude);
          NSLog(@"coordinate.longitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.longitude);
          NSLog(@"thoroughfare=%@", addressObj.thoroughfare);
          NSLog(@"locality=%@", addressObj.locality);
          NSLog(@"subLocality=%@", addressObj.subLocality);
          NSLog(@"administrativeArea=%@", addressObj.administrativeArea);
          NSLog(@"postalCode=%@", addressObj.postalCode);
          NSLog(@"country=%@", addressObj.country);
          NSLog(@"lines=%@", addressObj.lines);
      }
  }];
  ```

  }
  }